# wkhtmltopdf does not convert to pdf

Tags: html, laravel, pdf, snappy

[image]

Hi ,
I just changed my server and from what i understand i have installed all the dependencies required for this. But still i am unable to view my PDF instead a distorted code is shown and what's more annoying is that i have a bunch of projects in CODEIGNITOR Framework that are working fine but this project is developed in laarvel 5.
Is there any additional dependency for laravel or am i doing it wrong at some place.

I just joined a new team and don't know their whole programming structure yet.

Answer (score 0):

The image-content you posted looks like a valid PDF - looking at it by a text viewer. 
Did you try to open it with a pdf viewer?